# strpos not recognizing string

Tags: php

I have a short little function that I wrote to read through a CSS file and return the value of a property. The problem is that it reads right past the value that I want and returns a value further into the file that is the wrone one.

Here's the function;

```
function get_css($f, $tag, $el) {
$css = fopen($f, "r");
$line = fgets($css);
while ( !feof($css) ) {
    if(strpos($line, $tag) > 0) {
        while ( !feof($css) ) {
            $line = fgets($css);
            if (strpos($line, $el) > 0) {
                return substr(substr($line, strpos($line, ":")+1), 0, -1);
            }
        }
    }
    $line = fgets($css);
}
}
```

Here's how I call it;

```
$ew = get_css("1688_style.css", "elevations", "width");
```

and here's a sample of the CSS file that it's reading;

```
Body {
margin:0;
color:black;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:0px;
font-family:arial,sans-serif;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#Content {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
margin-top:30px;
margin-left:80px;
width:1520px;
}

#elevations {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:250px;
text-align:center;
}                   

#views {
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:15px;
}

#help {
 position:absolute;
 width:50px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:12px;
 top:18px;
 right:20px;
}
```

What I expect is 250px but what I get is the 50px from the #help tag. I've run out of ideas on what to try here.

Comment: Why are you writing a CSS parser? This sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Because the CSS files are created uniquely for the device that the user has. So to adjust the positioning of elements I want to be able to read how that element was defined.

Answer (score 3):

`strpos` will return 0 if the search string is at the start of the content, and `false` if it's not there at all. So...

```
if(strpos($line,$tag) > 0)
```

should be...

```
if(strpos($line,$tag) !== false)
```

Same goes for the other places you use `strpos`, and finally you can just remove the `+1` since it's not needed.